# Paypal SetExpressCheckout prefill address does not work java

Tags: java, paypal

I have the latests nvp sdk for java (76.0) and am I sending the params to paypal in the following way:

```
NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
encoder.add("VERSION", "76.0");
encoder.add("METHOD","SetExpressCheckout");
encoder.add("RETURNURL",returnURL);
encoder.add("CANCELURL",cancelURL);
encoder.add("AMT",request.getParameter("paymentAmount"));
encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",request.getParameter("paymentType"));
encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE",request.getParameter("currencyCodeType"));

encoder.add("LANDINGPAGE","Billing");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET", "345/3 Moomy St.");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY", "Umpa Lumpa");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME","Johnny Walker");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE", "NSW");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP","2673");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE", "AU");
encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT","56.00");
encoder.add("NOSHIPPING", "0");
```

I am getting to the "billing" landing page however I do not get a prefilled address. I have also tried exchanging:
    encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",request.getParameter("paymentType"));
with:
    encoder.add("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION",request.getParameter("paymentType"));

since the former seems to be deprecated.

I am using the same parameters as in:
[Is it possible to pass a shipping address via SetExpressCheckout when using PayPal Checkout Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653720/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-shipping-address-via-setexpresscheckout-when-using-payp)

There, an api upgrade seems to be the answer, however I have the latest. At least that is what `System.out.println("API VERSION: "+caller.getAPIVersion());` is telling me (76.0)

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved that **&*&@*&#@ Problem: It works with the normal old deprecated variables!!!! DO **NOT** USE:

PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ANYTHING it does not work!